# rails acts-as-taggable-on throwing error in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3p448.

acts-as-taggable-on works fine in development mode but in production mode it throws an error below.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `association_class' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44:in `block in define_readers'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb:284:in `tags_on'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb:249:in `tag_list_cache_on'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb:254:in `tag_list_on'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb:44:in `tag_list'
from (irb):1
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/navneet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: First upgrade rails to 3.2.15. Ther were serious bugs fixes since 3.2.1. Then check if problem still exist.

Comment: I have upgraded rails to 3.2.15 but the problem still exist.